# Parsing JSON response in React to State

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, state

I have an `API`, which sends me a `JSON` and I want to populate my state with it, but some variable names are different. Do I have to do everything separately or is there a method to do all of them at once?

My JSON from request:

```
{
   "name":"julps",
   "place": "house",
   "number":"555032",
   ...
   "products":[
      {
         "name":"name1",
         "id":"123456"
      },
      {
         "name":"name2",
         "id":"234567"
      }
   ],
}
```

My state:

```
this.state = {
  name: '',
  place: '',
  phone: '',
  ...
  things: []
};
```

And the fetch request:

```
  fetchEditData = (code) => {
    installationDocumentRequestApi(`/${code}`)
      .then((importedJson) => {
        if (importedJson != null) {
          this.setState({
            name: importedJson.name,
            place: importedJson.place,
            phone: importedJson.number,
            ...
            things: importedJson.products
          });
        }
      });
  };
```

In this example it would be fine to do them separately but in my actual example I have around 20 fields so I started wondering if there is a shorter way to do it or its the only possible solution.
Also If I could for example have all the same names then would it work without setting them separately?

Comment: What about using the rest/spread syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to do everything separately or is there a method to do all of them at once?

You do not have to do everything separately. And yes you have a way to get all of them at once.

I recommend you to make a state with all of your data. You will then access your data through that.

For exemple :

```
this.state = {
  data: null
};

... 

fetchEditData = (code) => {
    installationDocumentRequestApi(`/${code}`)
      .then((importedJson) => {
        if (importedJson != null) {
          this.setState({
            data: importedJson
          });
        }
      });
  };
```

And you can then get you data with your state. Like this for exemple `console.log(data.name)`.

As @evolutionxbox mentionned in comment it is maybe better for you to use the spread syntax `this.setState({ ...importedJson })`

Comment: My whole page uses the variables a bit differently so i would have to redo a lot since the method I am currently working is more like an AddOn of sorts.. but well thank you for the answer.

Comment: Why not use the spread syntax? `this.setState({ ...importedJson })`?

Comment: thats probably the way to go